# Keybinding Alt+Right Arrow to Function Key

Tags: keyboard, function-keys, shortcut-keys

I know how to keybind a terminal command to a function key, but how would I keybind a keyboard combination to a function key. For example in Chrome the command Alt+LeftArrow acts as moving to your previous webpage. I would like to press my F1 key instead of pressing Alt+LeftArrow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To change Ubuntu keyboard shortcuts, open the Keyboard settings, and go to the Shortcuts tab.

For changing Chrome mappings, see [this](https://superuser.com/questions/497526/how-to-customize-google-chrome-keyboard-shortcuts) superuser link.

For key-to-key bindings, see [dconf-editor](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Keybindings#DConf).

Comment: The link shows how to change shortcuts from within Chrome itself, but not how to do it locally in Ubuntu. When I press F1, I want it to behave as if I pressed Alt+LeftArrow, no matter if I am in Chrome or not. As per your first sentence, there's a difference between mapping commands and mapping keypresses.

Comment: Ah ok, sorry, then I did not understand your question correctly. I thought you meant that you wanted to use F1 for moving to previous webpage in Chrome.
In that case, I think you want [dconf-editor](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Keybindings#DConf)